# How make Route::resource with page and filter options?

Tags: laravel-5

In Laravel 5.8 making backend rest api app with resource defined in routes/api.php, as

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'adminarea', 'as' => 'adminarea.'], function ($router) {
    ...
    Route::resource('skills', 'API\Admin\SkillController');
```

now on clients part for listing of skills I need to add current_page and filter_name.
Can it be done with Route::resource definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when we making the resource controller in laravel then it created the method index
create,
store,
show,
edit,
update,
destroy.
method and routes of these respectively but when you are going to define the new method and for access this method then you need to create new route for this.
otherwise it is not possible with the resource route in laravel.

```
public function abc(Request $request)
{
     dd($request->all());
}
```

route for this
route::post('/abc','ABCController@abc')->name('abc');

you can check the route by this command

## php artisan route:list or

## php artisan r:l

hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

After some search I found a decision in defining in routes one more post route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'adminarea', 'as' => 'adminarea.'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('skills-filter', 'API\Admin\SkillController@filter');
    Route::resource('skills', 'API\Admin\SkillController');
    ...
```

and in app/Http/Controllers/API/Admin/SkillController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Admin;

use Auth;
use DB;
use Validator;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Resources\Admin\Skill as SkillResource;


class SkillController extends Controller
{
    private $requestData;
    private $page;
    private $filter_name;
    private $order_by;
    private $order_direction;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => []]);
        $request           = request();
        $this->requestData = $request->all();
    }

    public function filter()
    {
        if ( ! $this->checkUsersGroups([ACCESS_ROLE_ADMIN])) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
        $backend_items_per_page = Settings::getValue('backend_items_per_page');

        $this->page            = !empty($this->requestData['page']) ? $this->requestData['page'] : '';
        $this->filter_name     = !empty($this->requestData['filter_name']) ? $this->requestData['filter_name'] : '';
        $this->order_by        = !empty($this->requestData['order_by']) ? $this->requestData['order_by'] : 'name';
        $this->order_direction = !empty($this->requestData['order_direction']) ? $this->requestData['order_direction'] : 'asc';
        $this->index();
        $skills = Skill
            ::getByName($this->filter_name)
            ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)
            ->paginate($backend_items_per_page);

        return SkillResource::collection($skills);
    } // public function filter()


    public function index()
    {
        if ( ! $this->checkUsersGroups([ACCESS_ROLE_ADMIN])) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        $backend_items_per_page = Settings::getValue('backend_items_per_page');
        $skills = Skill::paginate($backend_items_per_page);
        return SkillResource::collection($skills);
    }
```

As that is adminarea some filter actions can have more 1 filter...

Just interested to know which other decisions are possible here?